# on y scroll down load dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function yHandler(){ 
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap'); 
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight; 
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight; 
if(y >= contentHeight){ 
wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>'; 
} 
} 


div#wrap{width:800px; margin:0px auto;}
div.newData{height:50px; background:#09F; margin:10px 0px;}
```

and these are the divs i have, currently on y scroll down it loads these light blue bars, but instead of these light blue bars i would like to load my conversations, how do i call my conversations

this is my y handler. and i want it to load conversations from my database when the page reaches the bottom, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX (I like to use it with PHP, but you can use other server-side languages to pass responses back). Where you have wrap.innerHTML += "";... use AJAX to get the results you want from your server-side page.

Brett McLaughlin wrote some great documentation on it on IBMs site, you can find it by Google searching "mastering ajax site:ibm.com filetype:pdf" without quotes...

Also, if you're into jQuery take a look at the $.ajax, $.post, or $.get functions.

Basically with jQuery you can call:

```
$.post(
     'serversidepage.php',
     attrs, //being an array filled with variables you want to use on the server
     function(data){
        wrap.innerHTML += data;
        //or data.html if you decide to use JSON / XML to pass back your data
     }
);
```

Then on your server, create the file 'serversidepage.php', and use the $_POST variables to determine what was sent using the attrs JS variable, and echo back what you want to return to the post command. Once it's back it will call the function within $.post, which will set that echoed data in your wrap element.

Comment: im a total beginner and i dont really know how to make sense of that answer

Comment: it seems like i have the answer right in front of me, i have these blue boxes appearing from nowhere as long as i scroll down, but i dont want blue boxes i want to replace the blue boxes with conversations from the database. in my mind all i have to do is replace one thing with another